# Xamarin Native Vs Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've  been  learning by my own Xamarin.Forms, to use in a project on my company.
Project Type - (Order Entry / Data Entry ).

The application is to use only in IPAD and Windows Tablets/PC. 
Until now I dint have many problems, only the Sqlite ORM is the sad part because I must MAP the dynamic querys, and cant use OleDB.
And also the UI is no so important, it can be the same UI on both platforms, the more important is the core business code.

I asked my boss to contact people that give formation in Xamarin, to present what is our project and where we want to go and to give some formation.

The first thing they presented me, with was that I shouldn't be constructing the application using Xamarin.Forms, but Xamarin Native.
And why(I asked) ? Because the Xamarin.Forms, the UI is good in Windows for example, but when I release to IPAD the UI will not be so good, and I will have major problems with that, and make tweaks to fix it, and the performance will drop for big Lists

And now I have 1/2 months of knowledge and work that probably I will not use and start a new project.

So my question is... 
Is this true? I know that  there is a topic in StackOverflow about this question, but with the Forms 2.0 maybe the game was changed.

My best Regards,
And thanks in advance :)

Comment: There are always different views on a technology and you could not stop that. Either you make the decision to listen, or you take the road you like. This question is almost impossible to be answered.

Answer (score 3):

Xamarin.Platform (aka Xamarin Native) is basically just regular Native App Development, except you use C# and can use portable class libraries.

So in the end you are still developing multiple native apps, just with all method names in Pascal casing.

Xamarin.Forms is a different product: It's a UI abstraction layer you can use to create a UI that runs on different platforms. It abstracts the native controls away into the lowest common denominator.

Of course that also means its not as perfect/good/... as a fully native UI, but that's the tradeoff you make for only developing it once.

Forms is useful, when your UI isn't too complex and doesn't rely too much on very special native controls.

Forms runs on top of Xamarin.Platform.